# $.get jquery function is returning a full html page instead of json in data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm developing a web app and I'm using php as server side language which return a JSON data here is the PHP script that is returning the JSON data:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";

if (isset($_GET['take'])) {

    $res = $conn->query('select * from pas where service=1');

}

if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($arr, $row);
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

the javascripte code is :

```
$.get('../controllers/sap.php?take=1', function(data) {
    console.log(data); //printing the result here
    console.log(data);
});
```

though yesterday it was working, that PHP page is the returned result....

[image: the response]

Comment: What HTML is it returning? Is it an error page for example?

Comment: @Chris it return the php page that i wrote not an error

Comment: So it isn't processing the PHP? Just returning the PHP code?

Comment: Put more effort into the question, I am still confused about what the response from controller.php is. Post screenshots of network tab, showing the response.

Comment: @Adam Azad I posted the response from the netwiork

Comment: @Chris the php by itself is returnung the json data if u open it from wamp serever,but if u access it with the get response it the result is returned the picture i posted above

Comment: @AbdallahSafieddine Why the browser is reading PHP code? Your server is not processing php code. Check your server's compatibility with php.

Comment: @AbdallahSafieddine Besides, you are missing `dataType` from the `$.get` function. You should specify `dataType` so that jQuery knows what type of data your are receiving.

Comment: @AnthonyLaw no it is proccessing it,if u open it as a link it returns json data,but if u access it through the get function is will return an html page...

Comment: From the code above, the PHP code is not completed with a `?>`. Are you posting a invalid code or you haven't completed the code? **Try cleaning your browser data / cache.** Your situation above is a bit surprised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107456/discussion-between-anthony-law-and-abdallah-safieddine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem,I was running the app from intelliJDea IDE on a diferent port than wamp server and php was not working on that port,but when I ran the app from wamp server it worked  since php is wroking thats the solution never run a php related app from any ID thats the lesson of the day :).